# Whats wrong with this phrase?

Tags: grammar

Is the phrase

`Tips on how tell the difference.`

Grammatically correct?

Should it be

`Tips on how to tell the difference.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct one is

"Tips on how to tell the difference."

"to" is a preposition and is needed to show the relationship between the subject "tips" and the object "tell the difference."